# How to remove file/folder from Docker container without starting this container

Tags: docker

How to remove file/folder from Docker container without starting this container? "Docker exec containerID rm filePath" can do it but it requires container in start state.

Comment: In particular, it requires /bin/rm, which might not even be in the image.

Answer (score 3):

The only other way I can find is to create a Dockerfile and put a `RUN rm /path/file/you/want/to/rm` into it...

Why want you to remove a file or a path without starting your container ?

Comment: I need to remove some files during restoring container. But I don't want to start this container because its entry point/command may do something.

Comment: Do you have the Dockerfile of your image or is it an official image ? If it's an official I don't think you can get the Dockerfile... But you can access to Dockerfile of any other images, then you can modify it by putting the line I told you to put before the entrypoint act :)

Comment: I have the same problem, I have copied 12 GB from the container to the host, the ORACLE_HOME, which I do prefer to have it on the host in case the container has to be re-created, now I would like to free the original folder... I believe one option is to go to /var/lib/docker/overlay2 and mess around...